# PDF to Raster image, mistake in render

Tags: imagemagick

I have deployed a PHP application to a new server with more recent version of ImageMagick and PHP, however, the new server (ImageMagick) does a poor job at converting PDF to raster (jpg or png).

Here is the PHP code I run on both servers (with identical input file)

```
$im = new Imagick();
$im->setResolution( 72, 72 );
$im->readImage( 'vector.pdf' );
$im->setImageFileName('output-old.jpg');
$im->writeImage();
```

The generated files look like this

**Generated file on old server (looks correct)**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/owai5.jpg

**Generated file on new server (problems)**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xg3kv.jpg

**Original PDF**
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9RgJSi9aRIJcUJYd2Z4bzFDTTA/view?usp=sharing

NOTE: same problem occurs when using ImageMagick via command line

```
convert vector.pdf output.jpg
```

**Old Server Configuration**

- PHP: 5.3.10
- ImageMagick: 6.7.6-0 2012-03-16 Q16
- OS: Ubuntu 12.04

**New Server Configuration**

- PHP: 5.6.13
- ImageMagick: 6.9.2-3 Q16 x86_64 2015-09-23
- OS: CentOs 6.5

You would expect the later version of ImageMagick to work better and would rather use that if possible.

Could the problem be in a configuration file or a dependant library? Will provide more server details if needed.

Comment: The version of ghostscript is older on the new server, that might me the problem, trying to upgrade ghostscript now.

Comment: You can also get a better output with `convert -density 144 vector.pdf output.jpg` by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by updating ghostscript

The new server only had ghostscript 8.7, I upgraded to 9.16

You can get you ghostscript version usually by running

```
gs --version
```